# getServerSide alternative in next 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a component (page), that uses "use client", and before rendering this page I want to fetch something from the server and redirect on some condition. How do I do that? In next < 13 i would just use getServerSideProps, but how do I deal with that in next 13.

So i tried to use useEffect with async function in it

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await fetch(...);
      const data = await res.json();
      
      if (data is incorrect) redirect(...)

      // rest of the code that runs after condition
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: The component should be a client component right? You could use [`useRouter`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router).

Comment: When using appDir, you should try to configure your app in next 13 way. Rather than making page client componet, leave it as it is, create another client component and render it in that page.

Answer (score 2):

In Next 13 app folder, a component declared in a file annotated by "use client" is executed on client side (browser) and works like a classic React component: you can use some hooks and manage users interactions.

To execute some code on server side, you have to create a server component (declared in a file without "use client"). A server component is asynchronous and cannot use hooks.

So in your case, you can just create a server Page component that fetch and display your data.

But if you need to interact with the user (using a Hook for example). You can simply create a server Page component that fetch your data and display a client component that interact with the user. Passing your data through props.

Note that you can pass data from server component to client component (with some date type restriction) but not the other way.

Nb: The redirect function can be used on server component to make redirect. For client you can use the useRouter Hook.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using appDir, then the page by default is serverside component. So, if you fetch anything in the page and pass it to children as a props, it should be equivalent to getServerSideProps. Only thing is, by default it is static.

eg.

```
// app/page.tsx

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

async function getPageData() {
  return  some data...
}


export default async function Page() {
   const data = await GetPageData();
   // if you don't need to use client component, then you can render here
   return <ChildPageComponent data={data} />
}
```

Remember: By default, all the pages are by default static. Which is equivalent to getStaticProps and getStaticPaths in page directory. To make the route segment dynamic you need to look into this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config.

So, rather than getting stuck, don't use use-client on page itself. Instead make the ChieldPageComponent the client component. You might have to use superjson with  next js for passing some data from server components to client components.